Автоматически создаются 2 гб. core файлы
В корневой папке сайта на постоянно основе стали создаваться core файлы, размером по 2 гб.
При выполнении команды: file core.1234
всплывают 2 типа ошибок в различныйх core файлах.

1 тип ошибки:
ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), too many program header sections (7986)

при выполнении команды gdb -c core.1234
всплывает ошибка:
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-120.el7
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type ""show copying""
and ""show warranty"" for details.
This GDB was configured as ""x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu"".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
BFD: Warning: /var/www/mywebsite.ru/data/www/mywebsite.ru/core.8648 is truncated: expected core file size >= 2186629120, found: 679276                      544.
[New LWP 8648]
[New LWP 8653]
[New LWP 8654]
[New LWP 8656]
[New LWP 8657]
[New LWP 8658]
[New LWP 8659]
[New LWP 8651]
[New LWP 8650]
[New LWP 8652]
[New LWP 8649]
Missing separate debuginfo for the main executable file
Try: yum --enablerepo='*debug*' install /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/da/37b4f7e97055c3dffa80997ec003396f77e0f8
Failed to read a valid object file image from memory.
Core was generated by `node /var/www/mywebsite.ru/data/www/mywebsite.ru/node_modules/.bin/frontity serve -'.
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x00007fca16ba5387 in ?? ()


2 тип ошибки:
ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from 'npm start', real uid: 1011, effective uid: 1011, real gid: 1011, effective gid: 1011, execfn: '/var/www/mywebsite.ru/data/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/node', platform: 'x86_64'

при выполнении команды gdb -c core.1234
всплывает ошибка:
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-120.el7
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
[New LWP 15613]
[New LWP 15617]
[New LWP 15616]
[New LWP 15618]
[New LWP 15615]
[New LWP 15614]
[New LWP 15620]
[New LWP 15621]
[New LWP 15623]
[New LWP 15619]
[New LWP 15622]
Missing separate debuginfo for the main executable file
Try: yum --enablerepo='*debug*' install /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/da/37b4f7e97055c3dffa80997ec003396f77e0f8
Core was generated by `npm start                                                                     '.
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f1b53843657 in ?? ()


Конфигурации VPS:

PHP 8.1.17 (alt)
FastCGI (Nginx + PHP-FPM)
Node.js 16.20.0
сайт на WordPress
панель управления ispmanager 6.5
OS CentOS 7

Вопрос: откуда взялась эта проблема и как ее исправить? Желательно средствами ispmanager!

Это дампы всей памяти сервера при обнаружении фатальных ошибок. Их размер 2 ГБ потому, что у вас, вероятно, размер памяти сервера равен 2 ГБ. Создаваться они не должны ни при каких ошибках в WordPress. Однако создаются, как мы видим в "Core was generated by node /var/www/mywebsite.ru/data/www/mywebsite.ru/node_modules/.bin/frontity serve...". Дело в неправильных настройках сервера. К WordPress вопрос отношения не имеет. Попробуйте запретить генерацию этих файлов командой ulimit -c 0`.


Это дампы всей памяти сервера при обнаружении фатальных ошибок.
благодарю за пояснение.


Их размер 2 ГБ потому, что у вас, вероятно, размер памяти сервера равен 2 ГБ.
создалась 2 типа core файлов на 2 гб и на 600 мб (2 разных типа ошибок)


Однако создаются, как мы видим в "Core was generated by node /var/www/mywebsite.ru/data/www/mywebsite.ru/node_modules/.bin/frontity serve...". Дело в неправильных настройках сервера.
Есть возможность обратиться к тех специалистам, которые отвечают за работу сервера.
Как им сформулировать задачу?



Это дампы всей памяти сервера при обнаружении фатальных ошибок.

благодарю за ответ


Их размер 2 ГБ потому, что у вас, вероятно, размер памяти сервера равен 2 ГБ.

cоздалась 2 типа core файлов на 2 гб и на 600 мб (2 разных типа ошибок)


Однако создаются, как мы видим в "Core was generated by node /var/www/mywebsite.ru/data/www/mywebsite.ru/node_modules/.bin/frontity serve...". Дело в неправильных настройках сервера.

Есть возможность обратиться к тех специалистам, которые отвечают за работу сервера. Как им сформулировать задачу?
